# Free API for exact date independent of the device

Tags: time

I have an android application and I need to use the exact date and I want it to be independent of local time(time of my device). Is there any API that I could use that does not return offset but the exact time?

Comment: use dates in utc

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. Even if I used utc, it would be dependent on the device time nonetheless.

Comment: I live in Argentina. Its 10am now => 1pm UTC. Its 4pm in Turkey. now => 1pm UTC. So we have the same time in utc, independently of the local time. Else its not clear what you need

Comment: If you change your phone's clock to 11 am, then your application is going to evaluate UTC time as 2pm. That is what causes inconsistency.